# Exists a variable that can receive string and int?both, like x= 1?

Tags: python, github

Im trying to make a '2 degree equation solver' to my github, **BUT** a equation recieve 'x' others letters and number how values.I need a variable that can recieve both values

```
def xcheck(x2, x, c):
 str(x2)
 str(x)
 str(c)

if x2 == ("ex: letter x"):
 float(x2 = 1)
```

I have tried to make a 'converter' but, clearly wouldn't work.

Comment: sorry for my english, i am learning yet

Comment: Understood.  Can you please provide some example inputs and their expected output? (The question is quite unclear)

Comment: If you want to solve `ax²+bx+c=0` you only need to pass the floats a,b,c. OR you only need to receive the string `ax²+bx+c=0`, and parse a,b,c from the string.